# ASP.NET MVC check for custom Attribute in Controller or Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute {  }

[MyAttribute]
public class MyControlller : Controller
{
      //...
}
```

Now that I have a `Global Action Filter` which gets me an `ActionExecutingContext` object.

My question is, here, how do I check if the requested `Controller` has been adorned with my custom `Attribute`.

Comment: If your filter is registered as a "global" filter then by default all requests to all your controller actions will pass through your filter.

Comment: @Matt, I understand that and that's what I want to do. But I would like to exclude some logic based on the Controller or Action. So, I thought it would be better to have an attribute set for such Action or Controller and check the same inside the filter method to exclude desired logic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
actionExecutingContextInstance.Controller.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0)
```

Or

```
actionExecutingContextInstance.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0)
```